# How to add a transition animation to a React menu toggle?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to add a transition animation to a React menu toggle but it's not working as expected. When the menu is toggled, I want the ul element to ease out smoothly. I have tried adding the transition CSS property to the ul element, but it's not working.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import menu from '../images/menu.svg'
import '../css/navbar.css'
import { FiMenu } from 'react-icons/fi'

function Navbar() {
  const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setShowMenu(!showMenu);
  };

  return (
    <>
    <div className="navbar bg-[#161616] w-screen h-16 shadow-[#48cae4] shadow-md flex justify-between items-center px-6">
          <div className="logo text-white font-bold text-2xl">My Logo</div>
          <div className={"menu sm:flex hidden"}>
              <ul className="flex text-center space-x-6 text-white">
                  <li>
                      <a href="#" className="hover:text-gray-400 ml-10">
                          Home
                      </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="#" className="hover:text-gray-400">
                          About
                      </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="#" className="hover:text-gray-400">
                          Services
                      </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="#" className="hover:text-gray-400">
                          Contact
                      </a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
          <FiMenu className="flex sm:hidden" size={25} color="white" onClick={toggleMenu} />
      </div>
      <ul className={`flex sm:hidden bg-[#161616] shadow-[#48cae4] shadow-md flex-col items-center pt-7 justify-center gap-3 text-white ${showMenu ? "block" : "hidden"}`}>
              <li>
                  <a href="#" className="hover:text-gray-400">
                      Home
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#" className="hover:text-gray-400">
                      About
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#" className="hover:text-gray-400">
                      Services
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#" className="hover:text-gray-400">
                      Contact
                  </a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

I have tried adding a transition tag to an external css file and tried adding a transition tag inline using tailwind css, none of which works. What i expect when the menu button is toggled, is that the elements come down easing in, instead of just abruptly appearing

Comment: The `display` property can't be animated. Look into CSS animations to animate in and out with other properties, for example: opacity and visibility.